# "Is robots.txt blocking important pages?" in Search Console regarding static folder

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, googlebot, robots.txt

This is the contents of my robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /static/*
Disallow: /templates/*
Disallow: /translations/*
Sitemap: https://xx.xxx.com/sitemap.xml
```

However I don't know why I am getting this error in Google Search Console:

[image: Is robots.txt blocking important pages? Some important page is blocked by robots.txt.]

Maybe due the static folder? So the question is, should I remove static folder from the robots?

[image: https://example.com/static/css/A.landing.css.pagespeed.cf.ScWDdlA8KO.css Style Sheet Blocked High robots.txt Tester]

Comment: You should state what is in your `/static` directory. We have to _assume_ that it's your JS and CSS files, and possibly images??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't block Googlebot from accessing your CSS.

- [Blocked Resources Report - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6153277)

  > JavaScript, CSS, and image files should be available to Googlebot so that it can see pages like an average user.
- [Updating our technical Webmaster Guidelines](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/10/updating-our-technical-webmaster.html)

  > Disallowing crawling of Javascript or CSS files in your site’s robots.txt directly harms how well our algorithms render and index your content and can result in suboptimal rankings.

Comment: Any official documentation about this?

Comment: @anvd There are so many sources for this, it's plastered everywhere across Google's documentation. I've added two to my answer.

Comment: That's like a good answer. One line answer always make doubt to newbie :)